# UICollectionViewCell content not stretched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UICollectionView` stretched across entire width of the screen. My `UICollectionViewCell`s are loaded from `MyViewCell.xib`. I set its size via:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) * 0.5, CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame));
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 16;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;  
}
```

And during main view controller loading I have:

```
[self.collView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
self.collView.delegate = self;
self.collView.dataSource = self;
```

This makes "cell view" of correct size, but its content loaded from XIB is still "small" and not strechted. This means, I can see two items on the screen, but they are not strechtech, only aligned to left and have fixed width around 50.

If I use the same code on iPhone, it is working correctly, problem is only with iPad. Both devices have same iOS version (10.3.3).

Comment: Can you log what `frame` size you get from `layoutSubviews()` methods, just to see if your cell gets to be correct size ...

Comment: Calls seem to be correct. If I log collectionView.frame size, that is entire screen and correct height, that is set in constraints.

Comment: Log what you get from `layoutSubviews()` in the cell itself as well

Comment: The frame is also correct, eg. same as what I have set in sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Do you use autolayout?

Comment: I have flow layout, I am using constraints for content of xib.

Comment: @matt I have already done that, all seems correct.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I ran your code and even on an iPad the cells are "stretched" as you are setting them. Something else is going on that you have not revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as given, works correctly. I translated it into Swift as follows (this is the *entirety* of my view controller's code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cv.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MyViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.cv.delegate = self
        self.cv.dataSource = self
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 16
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:self.cv.bounds.width/2, height:self.cv.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

This is what I see on the iPad simulator:

[image]

And that, given the default interitem spacing of 10, is just what I would expect to see.

The MyViewCell nib contains just a small yellow cell. I added the border just for clarity.

Comment: I have tried to add border around cell and border is correct. So the problem is in cell content, that is not stretched as in your example.

Comment: Oooooooh that's a good clue. So something is wrong with your _cell_ (probably in the nib). My cell in the nib is just a plain UICollectionViewCell with a yellow background color.

Comment: I have cleaned the project, rebuild, reset device and it started working.  However, thank your for your help. The trick with border did not crossed my mind.